# WIX MSI and Custom Action Progress

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I have an MSI that has 4 custom actions that are set to run after InstallFiles.  The custom actions work fine, but the progress bar in the MSI is very misleading.  To get to the point where the custom actions start probably takes about 10-15 seconds (it is a small MSI).  At this point, the progress bar is probably around 95%.  Each custom action takes about a minute each.  It takes about 15 seconds to get to 95% complete and 4 minutes to finish the last 5%.

Is there any way to to tell the installer that these custom actions will take a while to run?  For example, it would be nice if I could tell the installer that each custom action was 20% of the total time.  Therefore, everything up to the InstallFiles complete would be 20% complete and then after each custom action, it would add 20% complete.

I'm guessing there is not a way to do it (if there is, I missed it in the docs), but does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you seen this pat of the Windows Installer docs? [Adding Custom Actions to the ProgressBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367525)

Comment: I am actually wondering why the custom actions take that long - when they are that slow it tends to indicate an error prone design (no offence). I am a big fan of avoiding custom actions if at all possible, could you tell us what the custom actions are doing, and perhaps we might be able to suggest alternative approaches?

Comment: The custom actions are deploying database changes via a dacpac using SqlPackage.exe.  The database may not even be on the same machine, so that is the reason for the long run time.  We encompass everything in our installer - database, services, front ends, web sites, etc.  It is a "one click installer" to deploy our enterprise software (and it works well, just not quickly :-) ).

Comment: Hi @Steve0212, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly, I was pulled to higher priority work.  We have just lived with it...